# Python: Connect device using Visa TCP Socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, visa

In summary; I am trying to connect to a device using Visa TCP Socket option.

The Connection does not complain but I can not run any SCPI command to the device. Could this be because of an incorrect port number? => [Updated on 08/01/2021] No, 5025 is the correct port number, verified with the user manual. Still the error occurs.

Sample code in use:

```
import pyvisa as visa
import socket

try:
  resourceManager = visa.ResourceManager() 
  dev = 'TCPIP0::192.168.0.44::5025::SOCKET'
  session = resourceManager.open_resource(dev)
  print('\n Open Successful!')
  print('IDN:' +str(session.query('*IDN?')))

except Exception as e:
  print('[!] Exception:' +str(e))
```

I get the below response:
[image]

Thanks in advance!
P.S. I had no issues with GPIB, USB or other TCPIP connections.

Answer (score 3):

I have sorted this with the below modification, i.e. it was all about termination characters!
Hope this might help someone else having the same issue.

```
import pyvisa as visa
 
try:  
  resourceManager = visa.ResourceManager() 
  dev = 'TCPIP0::192.168.0.44::5025::SOCKET'
  session = resourceManager.open_resource(dev)
  print('\n Open Successful!')
  session.read_termination = '\n'
  session.write_termination = '\n'
  print('IDN:' +str(session.query('*IDN?')))
 
except Exception as e:
  print('[!] Exception:' +str(e))
```